# Special character broken after upgrade to Spring 4.3.16 from 4.1.2

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm working on a project which is primarily built on Java 8, Spring 4.1.2, Spring Integration 4.1.0, Spring Security 3.1.2, myBatis 3.2.3 and Tomcat 8.5 . There is a REST GET method exposed in the project which returns a JSON having the special character `é`.

Recently I've been trying to upgrade the whole project to Spring 4.3.16, Spring Integration 4.3.15 and Spring Security 4.2.4. After this migration, the special character shows up distorted. Postman requests to this service returns `\ufffd` in place of the character and the header `Content-Type →application/json`.

Prior to the Spring upgrade, GET requests to the function via Postman used to return the correct character and header 
`Content-Type →application/json;charset=UTF-8`

The same JSON is printed in logs and the special character shows up as `xE9` in Notepad++ and `é` in notepad.

I've tried the following-

1. Update `jackson-databind` from 2.4.1 to 2.8.11.2 - Did not work
2. Set `int-http:request-mapping consumes="application/json" produces="application/json;charset=UTF-8"` in the `int-http:inbound-gateway` - Did not work
3. Enable `setCharacterEncodingFilter` to `UTF-8` in Tomcat's `web.xml`- Did not work

Is there anything that needs to be changed for proper character encoding while migrating from Spring 4.1.2 to 4.3.16?

Thanks!

Comment: Any chances that you can share with us a simple test-case to reproduce? Maybe a project on GitHub, so we can pull it and play locally. Thanks

Comment: Hi @ArtemBilan , Thank you for the reply. I just found out the solution to my problem. I will add the answer.

Comment: Good. Let me know here when it is ready! I'm not going to be notified automatically because this is your question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue by referring to [Content-Type on http:inbound-gateway response has charset=iso-8859-1 instead of utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400813/content-type-on-httpinbound-gateway-response-has-charset-iso-8859-1-instead-of)

I added a header-enricher with the content-type as UTF-8.

```
 <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="Content-Length" expression="payload.length()"/>
        <int:header name="Content-Type" value="application/json;charset=UTF-8"/>
 </int:header-enricher>
```

Interestingly, this was not required prior to the Spring Upgrade. However, it works now.